# AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' python gui

Tags: python, mysql

I'm having this error AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode' and here is the part of my code. can you please help me

```
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM farm_registration \
       WHERE barangay = %s", (e_barangay);
cur.execute(sql)
results = cur.rowcount
```

Comment: can you post the whole code and the error stacktrace?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback

    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "/usr/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1562, in __call__

        return self.func(*args)

      File "/home/pi/Desktop/pow.py", line 415, in put

        cur.execute(sql)

      File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 536, in execute

        stmt = operation.encode(self._connection.python_charset)

    AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'encode'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement returns a tuple

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM farm_registration \
       WHERE barangay = %s", (e_barangay);
```

which you are expecting string instead, so just changed the above into

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM farm_registration \
       WHERE barangay = %s" % e_barangay;
```

Comment: we did that but now we have this error :mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''Saguing'' at line 1, my input at baranggay is Saguing

Comment: how about using something like this: sql = "SELECT * FROM farm_registration WHERE barangay = %s"
cur.execute(sql, (e_barangay))

Comment: thank you @johnIl but the problem is it should be sql = "SELECT * FROM farm_registration WHERE barangay = '%s'" % e_barangay the '' on %s is missing. but thanks anyway